# disable a series in StackedXYAreaChart - jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to create a user filter which would enable/disable a series based on the user click. I have added a checkbox button which will enable/disable the series.

When I click the button, only the legend item disappears. The area on the plot still remains visible. Is my approach wrong? Or is this not possible in StackedXYAreaChart? What am I doing wrong ?

```
package test;   

import java.awt.BorderLayout;   
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;   
import org.jfree.chart.*;   
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;   
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;   
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;   
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StackedXYAreaRenderer2;   
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;   

public class Test2   
{   

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   

public Test2(String s)   
{     
    JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());  
    JPanel jpanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart);   
    JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    masterPanel.add(jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    masterPanel.add(addUserControls(jfreechart), BorderLayout.EAST);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(masterPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}   

private static TableXYDataset createDataset()   
{   
    DefaultTableXYDataset defaulttablexydataset = new DefaultTableXYDataset();   
    XYSeries xyseries = new XYSeries("Series 1", true, false);   
    xyseries.add(5D, 5D);   
    xyseries.add(10D, 15.5D);   
    xyseries.add(15D, 9.5D);   
    xyseries.add(20D, 7.5D);   
    defaulttablexydataset.addSeries(xyseries);   
    XYSeries xyseries1 = new XYSeries("Series 2", true, false);   
    xyseries1.add(5D, 5D);   
    xyseries1.add(10D, 15.5D);   
    xyseries1.add(15D, 9.5D);   
    xyseries1.add(20D, 3.5D);   
    defaulttablexydataset.addSeries(xyseries1);   
    return defaulttablexydataset;   
}   

private static JFreeChart createChart(TableXYDataset tablexydataset)   
{   
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart("Stacked XY Area Chart Demo 1", "X Value", "Y Value", tablexydataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);   
    XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();   
    StackedXYAreaRenderer2 stackedxyarearenderer2 = new StackedXYAreaRenderer2();   
    stackedxyarearenderer2.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());   
    xyplot.setRenderer(0, stackedxyarearenderer2);   
    return jfreechart;   
}   

public static JPanel createDemoPanel()   
{   
    JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());   
    return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);   
}   

public static void main(String args[])   
{   
    Test2 stackedxyareachartdemo1 = new Test2("Stacked XY Area Chart Demo 1");   
}   

public JPanel addUserControls(JFreeChart chartPlot) {
    JPanel userPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JCheckBox dataButton = new JCheckBox("Data");
    dataButton.setSelected(true);
    dataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (dataButton.isSelected()) {
            StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
            renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, Boolean.TRUE);
            } else {
                StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        }
    });
    userPanel.add(dataButton);
    return userPanel;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is described [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30363) for `StackedXYBarRenderer`.

The simplest solution is to override the default renderer's `drawItem()` method to enforce visibility:

```
public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2,
                     XYItemRendererState state,
                     Rectangle2D dataArea,
                     PlotRenderingInfo info,
                     XYPlot plot,
                     ValueAxis domainAxis,
                     ValueAxis rangeAxis,
                     XYDataset dataset,
                     int series,
                     int item,
                     CrosshairState crosshairState,
                     int pass) {
    if (!getItemVisible(series, item)) {
        return;
    }
    super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, info, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, series, item, crosshairState, pass);
}
```

However, then the output might not be the expected one:

[image]

There are more sophisticated proposals following the link above.

Comment: This helps completely ! Thank you so much. I hope this bug is resolved in the future !

Answer (score 0):

Here's my modified code according to the answer described above:

```
package test;   

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;   
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
 import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;   
 import org.jfree.chart.*;   
 import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
 import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;   
 import org.jfree.chart.plot.CrosshairState;
 import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;   
 import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
 import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;   
 import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StackedXYAreaRenderer2;   
 import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRendererState;
 import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
 import org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset;
 import org.jfree.data.xy.*;   

public class Test2   
{   

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   

public Test2(String s)   
{     
    JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());  
    JPanel jpanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart);   
    JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    masterPanel.add(jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    masterPanel.add(addUserControls(jfreechart), BorderLayout.EAST);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(masterPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}   

private static TimeTableXYDataset createDataset()   
{   
    TimeTableXYDataset xyseries = new TimeTableXYDataset();

    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 5D, "Series 1");   
    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 10D, "Series 1");   
    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 15D, "Series 1");   
    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 20D, "Series 1");   

    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 15D, "Series 2");   
    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 20D, "Series 2");   
    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 25D, "Series 2");   
    xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 30D, "Series 2");   

    return xyseries;   
}   

private static JFreeChart createChart(TableXYDataset tablexydataset)   
{   
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart("Stacked XY Area Chart Demo 1", "X Value", "Y Value", tablexydataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);   
    XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();   
    StackedXYAreaRenderer2 stackedxyarearenderer2 = new StackedXYAreaRenderer2() {
        public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2,
                 XYItemRendererState state,
                 Rectangle2D dataArea,
                 PlotRenderingInfo info,
                 XYPlot plot,
                 ValueAxis domainAxis,
                 ValueAxis rangeAxis,
                 XYDataset dataset,
                 int series,
                 int item,
                 CrosshairState crosshairState,
                 int pass) {
if (!getItemVisible(series, item)) {
    return;
}
super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, info, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, series, item, crosshairState, pass);
}
    };   
    stackedxyarearenderer2.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());   
    xyplot.setRenderer(0, stackedxyarearenderer2);   
    return jfreechart;   
}   

public static JPanel createDemoPanel()   
{   
    JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());   
    return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);   
}   

public static void main(String args[])   
{   
    Test2 stackedxyareachartdemo1 = new Test2("Stacked XY Area Chart Demo 1");   
}   

public JPanel addUserControls(JFreeChart chartPlot) {
    JPanel userPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JCheckBox Series0Button = new JCheckBox("Series 1");
    Series0Button.setSelected(true);
    Series0Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Series count" + chartPlot.getXYPlot().getSeriesCount());
            if (Series0Button.isSelected()) {
            StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
            renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, Boolean.TRUE, true);
            } else {
                StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, Boolean.FALSE, true);
            }
        }
    });

    JCheckBox series1Button = new JCheckBox("Series 2");
    series1Button.setSelected(true);
    series1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (series1Button.isSelected()) {
            StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
            renderer.setSeriesVisible(1, Boolean.TRUE, true);
            } else {
                StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                renderer.setSeriesVisible(1, Boolean.FALSE, true);
            }
        }
    });
    userPanel.add(Series0Button);
    userPanel.add(series1Button);
    return userPanel;
}
}
```